# a simple function

Tags: c++

Hi all
I need to declare a variable in Node to keep position of that node so I declare it in node.h

like: `std::vector<double> exPosition;(public)`

then I defined a simple function for getting this variable like:virtual Vector

```
GetmyPosition (void) const=0;
```

then in node.cc I wrote this simple function:

```
node::GetmyPosition (void) const
{
  return exPosition;
}
```

but when i run it it has this error:

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'ns3::Node'
note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'ns3::Node';
```

here is the complete code for node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <vector>

#include "ns3/object.h"
#include "ns3/callback.h"
#include "ns3/ptr.h"
#include "ns3/net-device.h"

namespace ns3 {

class Application;
class Packet;
class Address;


/**
 * \ingroup node
 *
 * \brief A network Node.
 *
 * This class holds together:
 *   - a list of NetDevice objects which represent the network interfaces
 *     of this node which are connected to other Node instances through
 *     Channel instances.
 *   - a list of Application objects which represent the userspace
 *     traffic generation applications which interact with the Node
 *     through the Socket API.
 *   - a node Id: a unique per-node identifier.
 *   - a system Id: a unique Id used for parallel simulations.
 *
 * Every Node created is added to the NodeList automatically.
 */
class Node : public Object
{
public:
   /// exposition of the node
  //std::vector<Ptr<Node> > exPosition;
  std::vector<double> exPosition;
  /// current position of the node
  //std::vector<double> cPosition;  
  static TypeId GetTypeId (void);

  /**
   * Must be invoked by subclasses only.
   */
  Node();
  /**
   * \param systemId a unique integer used for parallel simulations.
   *
   * Must be invoked by subclasses only.
   */
  Node(uint32_t systemId);

  virtual ~Node();

  /**
   * \returns the unique id of this node.
   * 
   * This unique id happens to be also the index of the Node into
   * the NodeList. 
   */
  uint32_t GetId (void) const;

  /**
   * \returns the system id for parallel simulations associated
   *          to this node.
   */
  uint32_t GetSystemId (void) const;

  /**
   * \param device NetDevice to associate to this node.
   * \returns the index of the NetDevice into the Node's list of
   *          NetDevice.
   *
   * Associate this device to this node.
   */
  uint32_t AddDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device);
  /**
   * \param index the index of the requested NetDevice
   * \returns the requested NetDevice associated to this Node.
   *
   * The indexes used by the GetDevice method start at one and
   * end at GetNDevices ()
   */
  Ptr<NetDevice> GetDevice (uint32_t index) const;
  /**
   * \returns the number of NetDevice instances associated
   *          to this Node.
   */
  uint32_t GetNDevices (void) const;

  /**
   * \param application Application to associate to this node.
   * \returns the index of the Application within the Node's list
   *          of Application.
   *
   * Associated this Application to this Node. This method is called
   * automatically from Application::Application so the user
   * has little reasons to call this method directly.
   */
  uint32_t AddApplication (Ptr<Application> application);
  /**
   * \param index
   * \returns the application associated to this requested index
   *          within this Node.
   */
  Ptr<Application> GetApplication (uint32_t index) const;

  /**
   * \returns the number of applications associated to this Node.
   */
  uint32_t GetNApplications (void) const;

  /**
   * A protocol handler
   *
   * \param device a pointer to the net device which received the packet
   * \param packet the packet received
   * \param protocol the 16 bit protocol number associated with this packet.
   *        This protocol number is expected to be the same protocol number
   *        given to the Send method by the user on the sender side.
   * \param sender the address of the sender
   * \param receiver the address of the receiver; Note: this value is
   *                 only valid for promiscuous mode protocol
   *                 handlers.  Note:  If the L2 protocol does not use L2
   *                 addresses, the address reported here is the value of 
   *                 device->GetAddress().
   * \param packetType type of packet received
   *                   (broadcast/multicast/unicast/otherhost); Note:
   *                   this value is only valid for promiscuous mode
   *                   protocol handlers.  
   */
  typedef Callback<void,Ptr<NetDevice>, Ptr<const Packet>,uint16_t,const Address &,
                   const Address &, NetDevice::PacketType> ProtocolHandler;
  /**
   * \param handler the handler to register
   * \param protocolType the type of protocol this handler is 
   *        interested in. This protocol type is a so-called
   *        EtherType, as registered here:
   *        http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/ethertype/eth.txt
   *        the value zero is interpreted as matching all
   *        protocols.
   * \param device the device attached to this handler. If the
   *        value is zero, the handler is attached to all
   *        devices on this node.
   * \param promiscuous whether to register a promiscuous mode handler
   */
  void RegisterProtocolHandler (ProtocolHandler handler, 
                                uint16_t protocolType,
                                Ptr<NetDevice> device,
                                bool promiscuous=false);
  /**
   * \param handler the handler to unregister
   *
   * After this call returns, the input handler will never
   * be invoked anymore.
   */
  void UnregisterProtocolHandler (ProtocolHandler handler);


  /**
   * \returns true if checksums are enabled, false otherwise.
   */
  static bool ChecksumEnabled (void);


protected:
  /**
   * The dispose method. Subclasses must override this method
   * and must chain up to it by calling Node::DoDispose at the
   * end of their own DoDispose method.
   */
  virtual void DoDispose (void);
  virtual void DoStart (void);
private:

  /**
   * \param device the device added to this Node.
   *
   * This method is invoked whenever a user calls Node::AddDevice.
   */
  virtual void NotifyDeviceAdded (Ptr<NetDevice> device);
  bool NonPromiscReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet>, uint16_t protocol, const Address &from);
  bool PromiscReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet>, uint16_t protocol,
                                 const Address &from, const Address &to, NetDevice::PacketType packetType);
  bool ReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet>, uint16_t protocol,
                          const Address &from, const Address &to, NetDevice::PacketType packetType, bool promisc);

  void Construct (void);

  struct ProtocolHandlerEntry {
    ProtocolHandler handler;
    Ptr<NetDevice> device;
    uint16_t protocol;
    bool promiscuous;
  };
  typedef std::vector<struct Node::ProtocolHandlerEntry> ProtocolHandlerList;
  uint32_t    m_id;         // Node id for this node
  uint32_t    m_sid;        // System id for this node
  std::vector<Ptr<NetDevice> > m_devices;
  std::vector<Ptr<Application> > m_applications;
  ProtocolHandlerList m_handlers;

};

} //namespace ns3

#endif /* NODE_H */
```

and also the complete code for node.cc

```
/* -*- Mode:C++; c-file-style:"gnu"; indent-tabs-mode:nil; -*- */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Georgia Tech Research Corporation, INRIA
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation;
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 *
 * Authors: George F. Riley<riley@ece.gatech.edu>
 *          Mathieu Lacage <mathieu.lacage@sophia.inria.fr>
 */
#include "node.h"
#include "node-list.h"
#include "net-device.h"
#include "application.h"
#include "ns3/packet.h"
#include "ns3/simulator.h"
#include "ns3/object-vector.h"
#include "ns3/uinteger.h"
#include "ns3/log.h"
#include "ns3/assert.h"
#include "ns3/global-value.h"
#include "ns3/boolean.h"
#include "ns3/simulator.h"
#include "ns3/vector.h"

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("Node");

namespace ns3{

NS_OBJECT_ENSURE_REGISTERED (Node);

GlobalValue g_checksumEnabled  = GlobalValue ("ChecksumEnabled",
                                              "A global switch to enable all checksums for all protocols",
                                              BooleanValue (false),
                                              MakeBooleanChecker ());
//Vector exposition = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
/*.AddAttribute ("exPosition", "The previous position of this node.",
                   TypeId::ATTR_GET,
                   VectorValue (Vector (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), // ignored initial value.
                   MakeVectorAccessor (&Node::m_exposition),
                   MakeVectorChecker ())
    .AddAttribute ("cPosition", "The current position of this node.",
                   TypeId::ATTR_GET,
                   VectorValue (Vector (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), // ignored initial value.
                   MakeVectorAccessor (&Node::m_cposition),
                   MakeVectorChecker ())*/


TypeId 
Node::GetTypeId (void)
{
  static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::Node")
    .SetParent<Object> ()
    .AddConstructor<Node> ()
    .AddAttribute ("DeviceList", "The list of devices associated to this Node.",
                   ObjectVectorValue (),
                   MakeObjectVectorAccessor (&Node::m_devices),
                   MakeObjectVectorChecker<NetDevice> ())
    .AddAttribute ("ApplicationList", "The list of applications associated to this Node.",
                   ObjectVectorValue (),
                   MakeObjectVectorAccessor (&Node::m_applications),
                   MakeObjectVectorChecker<Application> ())
    .AddAttribute ("Id", "The id (unique integer) of this Node.",
                   TypeId::ATTR_GET, // allow only getting it.
                   UintegerValue (0),
                   MakeUintegerAccessor (&Node::m_id),
                   MakeUintegerChecker<uint32_t> ())


    ;
  return tid;
}

Node::Node()
  : m_id(0), 
    m_sid(0)
{
  exPosition.at(1)= 0;
  exPosition.at(2)= 0;
  exPosition.at(3)= 0;

  Construct ();
}

Node::Node(uint32_t sid)
  : m_id(0), 
    m_sid(sid)
{ 
  exPosition.at(1)= 0;
  exPosition.at(2)= 0;
  exPosition.at(3)= 0;
  Construct ();
}

void
Node::Construct (void)
{
  m_id = NodeList::Add (this);
  //exPosition =(0.0,0.0,0.0);
}

Node::~Node ()
{}

uint32_t 
Node::GetId (void) const
{
  return m_id;
}

uint32_t 
Node::GetSystemId (void) const
{
  return m_sid;
}

uint32_t 
Node::AddDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device)
{
  uint32_t index = m_devices.size ();
  m_devices.push_back (device);
  device->SetNode (this);
  device->SetIfIndex(index);
  device->SetReceiveCallback (MakeCallback (&Node::NonPromiscReceiveFromDevice, this));
  Simulator::ScheduleWithContext (GetId (), Seconds (0.0), 
                                  &NetDevice::Start, device);
  NotifyDeviceAdded (device);
  return index;
}
Ptr<NetDevice>
Node::GetDevice (uint32_t index) const
{
  NS_ASSERT_MSG (index < m_devices.size (), "Device index " << index <<
                 " is out of range (only have " << m_devices.size () << " devices).");
  return m_devices[index];
}
uint32_t 
Node::GetNDevices (void) const
{
  return m_devices.size ();
}

uint32_t 
Node::AddApplication (Ptr<Application> application)
{
  uint32_t index = m_applications.size ();
  m_applications.push_back (application);
  application->SetNode (this);
  Simulator::ScheduleWithContext (GetId (), Seconds (0.0), 
                                  &Application::Start, application);
  return index;
}
Ptr<Application> 
Node::GetApplication (uint32_t index) const
{
  NS_ASSERT_MSG (index < m_applications.size (), "Application index " << index <<
                 " is out of range (only have " << m_applications.size () << " applications).");
  return m_applications[index];
}
uint32_t 
Node::GetNApplications (void) const
{
  return m_applications.size ();
}

void 
Node::DoDispose()
{
  m_handlers.clear ();
  for (std::vector<Ptr<NetDevice> >::iterator i = m_devices.begin ();
       i != m_devices.end (); i++)
    {
      Ptr<NetDevice> device = *i;
      device->Dispose ();
      *i = 0;
    }
  m_devices.clear ();
  for (std::vector<Ptr<Application> >::iterator i = m_applications.begin ();
       i != m_applications.end (); i++)
    {
      Ptr<Application> application = *i;
      application->Dispose ();
      *i = 0;
    }
  m_applications.clear ();
  Object::DoDispose ();
}
void 
Node::DoStart (void)
{
  for (std::vector<Ptr<NetDevice> >::iterator i = m_devices.begin ();
       i != m_devices.end (); i++)
    {
      Ptr<NetDevice> device = *i;
      device->Start ();
    }
  for (std::vector<Ptr<Application> >::iterator i = m_applications.begin ();
       i != m_applications.end (); i++)
    {
      Ptr<Application> application = *i;
      application->Start ();
    }

  Object::DoStart ();
}

void 
Node::NotifyDeviceAdded (Ptr<NetDevice> device)
{}

void
Node::RegisterProtocolHandler (ProtocolHandler handler, 
                               uint16_t protocolType,
                               Ptr<NetDevice> device,
                               bool promiscuous)
{
  struct Node::ProtocolHandlerEntry entry;
  entry.handler = handler;
  entry.protocol = protocolType;
  entry.device = device;
  entry.promiscuous = promiscuous;

  // On demand enable promiscuous mode in netdevices
  if (promiscuous)
    {
      if (device == 0)
        {
          for (std::vector<Ptr<NetDevice> >::iterator i = m_devices.begin ();
               i != m_devices.end (); i++)
            {
              Ptr<NetDevice> dev = *i;
              dev->SetPromiscReceiveCallback (MakeCallback (&Node::PromiscReceiveFromDevice, this));
            }
        }
      else
        {
          device->SetPromiscReceiveCallback (MakeCallback (&Node::PromiscReceiveFromDevice, this));
        }
    }

  m_handlers.push_back (entry);
}

void
Node::UnregisterProtocolHandler (ProtocolHandler handler)
{
  for (ProtocolHandlerList::iterator i = m_handlers.begin ();
       i != m_handlers.end (); i++)
    {
      if (i->handler.IsEqual (handler))
        {
          m_handlers.erase (i);
          break;
        }
    }
}

bool
Node::ChecksumEnabled (void)
{
  BooleanValue val;
  g_checksumEnabled.GetValue (val);
  return val.Get ();
}

bool
Node::PromiscReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet> packet, uint16_t protocol,
                                const Address &from, const Address &to, NetDevice::PacketType packetType)
{
  NS_LOG_FUNCTION(this);
  return ReceiveFromDevice (device, packet, protocol, from, to, packetType, true);
}

bool
Node::NonPromiscReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet> packet, uint16_t protocol,
                                   const Address &from)
{
  NS_LOG_FUNCTION(this);
  return ReceiveFromDevice (device, packet, protocol, from, from, NetDevice::PacketType (0), false);
}

bool
Node::ReceiveFromDevice (Ptr<NetDevice> device, Ptr<const Packet> packet, uint16_t protocol,
                         const Address &from, const Address &to, NetDevice::PacketType packetType, bool promiscuous)
{
  NS_ASSERT_MSG (Simulator::GetContext () == GetId (), "Received packet with erroneous context ; " <<
                 "make sure the channels in use are correctly updating events context " <<
                 "when transfering events from one node to another.");
  NS_LOG_DEBUG("Node " << GetId () << " ReceiveFromDevice:  dev "
               << device->GetIfIndex () << " (type=" << device->GetInstanceTypeId ().GetName ()
               << ") Packet UID " << packet->GetUid ());
  bool found = false;

  for (ProtocolHandlerList::iterator i = m_handlers.begin ();
       i != m_handlers.end (); i++)
    {
      if (i->device == 0 ||
          (i->device != 0 && i->device == device))
        {
          if (i->protocol == 0 || 
              i->protocol == protocol)
            {
              if (promiscuous == i->promiscuous)
                {
                  i->handler (device, packet, protocol, from, to, packetType);
                  found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return found;
}

}//namespace ns3
```

I'll be thankful if someone help me about it.
Bests
Bahar

Comment: Can you post the problematic code in its entirety here? Posting only individual lines does not give enough information for an adequate answer.

Comment: Also, please **accept** answers to your questions ! How do you expect people to answser when they know for sure they won't be rewarded ?

Comment: Somewhat difficult to answer without knowing (a) the rest of the error message and (b) the definition of the classes that `ns3::Node` inherits from, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: all the errore was that two I mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an object that has a virtual function declared as `=0`.
You can have pointers to them, but the pointed elements will actually have a type that inherits from your base class.

Comment: I deleted the =o but said :GetmyPosition (void) const doesn't match any in class ns3::Node and can't overload it what should I do?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example? I think you have neither a '=o' nor any ':GetmyPosition' anywhere, these should be typos. Creating the example may help you to identify the problem or give a question that's easier to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

GetMyPosition is defined, does it need to be pure virtual? Have you tried removing `=0` from function declaration?

Comment: what can I do? should I replace it by sth else?

Comment: I post it in a new question would u plz answer it

Comment: Ok, one more thing: post the whole error message. Gcc says "note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'ns3::Node'" and than the list of problematic functions. We need this list.

Comment: Post the solution here please, just in case someone has the same problem

Comment: i didn't need to define any function for this reason just I must declare it as: std::vector <double> exPosition;

Comment: then in .cc file and in constructor I just resize it and finally set initial value for my vector.